# run the command that corresponds to your operating system

Tags: corda

when i run  [enter image description here],it show bash: workflows-java/build/nodes/run-nodes : No such file or directory.
Thanks.

> workflows-java/build/nodes/run-nodes

[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs is currently being updated to accommodate the code changes in the cordapp-example repo.

The correct instruction for Linux and MacOs is:

```
./gradlew deployNodes
./build/nodes/runnodes
```

Comment: when i  run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.example.state.IOUState             
Could not parse as a command: Cannot construct instance of `java.lang.Class`, problem: com.example.state.IOUState
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

Comment: I run flow start ExampleFlow$Initiator iouValue: 50, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US" is sucess,but Checking the output is fail